# How to pass id from flask app to mysql database

Tags: python, flask, get, flask-restful

I have a flask application that is connected to the MySQL database.

> NOTE
>
> database name =  evaluation
>
> table name = evaluation
>
> columns = eval_id, eval_name, date

I have an 'evaluation table' with field eval_id, eval_name and date in it.

```
 mysql> use evaluation;
    mysql> describe evaluation;
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | eval_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | eval_name | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | date      | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How can I write an API to get a particular evaluation by its id?
I tried the below,  but it doesn't work.

```
@app.route('/getEval/<int:eval_id>', methods=['GET'])
def getEvalByID(eval_id):
    cur.execute('''select * from evaluation.evaluation where eval_id=eval_id''')
    res = cur.fetchall()
    return jsonify({'test':str(res)})
```

How can I correct this and get only the evaluation based on the eval_id mentioned in the app.route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the eval_id not as String but as a VAR.

```
@app.route('/getEval/<int:eval_id>', methods=['GET'])
def getEvalByID(eval_id):
    cur.execute('select * from evaluation.evaluation where eval_id=' + str(eval_id))
    res = cur.fetchall()
    return jsonify({'test':str(res)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i get the below error `cur.execute('select * from evaluation.evaluation where eval_id=' + eval_id, '')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Comment: fixed. try it now

Comment: Now i get `query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: The creation of the string in the `cur.execute` line is mixed. It does not pass a single string as argument. Try this: `'select * from evaluation.evaluation where eval_id=' + str(eval_id)`

Comment: if args are null we can get rid of them , try it with single argument as fixed again :O

Comment: @rocksteady Thanks your reply helped.

Answer (score 0):

try with cur.execute('select * from evaluation.evaluation where eval_id={}'.format(eval_id))